# Reset the counter of references in each chapter

Tags: biblatex, numbering, subdividing

I am currently busy with writing my PhD book in LaTeX. I want to have separate references list at the end of each chapter. 
Thanks to my colleague, we have added some line for this purpose and it works great at the moment. The problem now is that the counter continues increasing from the previous chapter. I want to have complete separate references list for each chapter, meaning that the counter should start from 1 for each chapter. Could you please tell me if there is any short solution like an option for this purpose?

```
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=ieee,natbib=true]{biblatex} 

\addbibresource{bibliography/ref.bib}

\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{refsegment=chapter,
firstinits=true,backref=true,backrefstyle=two,block=space,defernumbers=true}

\newcommand{\printreferences}%
{\printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment ,heading=myref]}
\defbibheading{myref}{%
\chapter*{References}
```

then at the and of each chapter I use

```
\printreferences
```

Thanks for any comment.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the `refsection` instead of the `refsegment` environment. Quoting section 3.6.5 of the manual:

> The difference between a `refsection` and a `refsegment` environment
>   is that the former creates labels which are local to the environment
>   whereas the latter provides a target for the segment filter of
>   `\printbibliography` without affecting the labels. They will be unique
>   across the entire document.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[refsection=section]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
@misc{B02,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Bravo},
}
@misc{C03,
  author = {Cuthor, C.},
  year = {2003},
  title = {Charlie},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\section{First}

Some  text \autocite{A01,B02}.

\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]

\section{Second}

Some  text \autocite{A01,C03}.

\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick reply.

I have just changed the code. It doesn't shoot any error but doesn't show any references though. I am digging in although I am pretty new in LaTeX.

Comment: I compiled it with \usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=ieee,natbib=true, refsection=section]{biblatex} and still no joy.

Comment: Does it work it `nocite{*}`? Say, one chapter only has `nocite{*}`, will it still work?

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code along these lines and be sure to use `biber` instead of `bibtex`. `bibtex` does not have all the features of `biber` which is the default reference generator for `biblatex`.

```
\usepackage[style=ieee,natbib=true]{biblatex} %default backend is biber 

\newcommand{\printreferences}%
{\printbibliography[section=\therefsection ,heading=myref]}

\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{refsection=chapter,
firstinits=true,backref=true,backrefstyle=two,block=space,defernumbers=true}
\markboth{#1}{#1}}
```