# Create per chapter bibliography

Tags: biblatex

My university has provided a template for writing the thesis.
However, it only prints the bibliography in the end of the thesis.

I would like to print bibliography per chapter. Can you please help?

Thanks a lot.
Regards

Comment: You might be interested  in § 3.7.4 *Bibliography sections*, pp. 85-86 in the documentation of `biblatex`.

Comment: You could use `chapterbib` package that is created for this usage. See how in the related (if not a duplicate) here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/333617/how-to-use-chapterbib-package-syntax

Comment: I have added an answer that shows how this could work. If you are having trouble getting things to run, you should really show us a short example document that reproduces the error you get. We can only tell you what is going wrong if we get to see what you are doing.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/moewew/13a85c603df482d03a456827b247aaa9 shows how one could turn the four-step instruction which included downloading files from elsewhere and unpacking them into a short MWE. Please try to show minimal example documents like this in the future. It is more time consuming to come up with short examples than just dumping all your code on people, but you will get better help much quicker if you don't smother people with walls of code.

Comment: @Rouge No one is being unfriendly of bullying anyone. Then thing is that when it comes to LaTeX, it's _really_ hard to give a useful answer without seeing the preamble of your document. People are here to help you, otherwise they would be doing other things in their spare time. moewe is an expert in bibliographies, his answer will most certainly point you in the right way. I'll roll back your edit so people who see this question in the future might benefit from it.

Comment: @phelype, I think people are answering questions to improve themselves and ofcourse to help others. So there should be no reason to use unfriendly language! In no way I think these following words are friendly or supportive- dumping my code/smothering people. I do not think you should encourage/support it. I can understand it is really hard to give a useful answer without seeing a preamble. That is why I posted, which I thought was the minimal example I could provide.

Comment: I'm sorry that I upset you. I didn't expect that those two phrases would offend you (or indeed anyone else), but I'm not a native English speaker, so I do not necessarily know all the connotations that they entail. I hoped that the comment could help you improve your questions in the future: It is a simple matter of fact that people are more inclined (and able) to help you if your code example are compact. If they don't feel like unloading a lot of code. If they don't require visiting other webpages and downloading and unpacking `.zip` files.  ...

Comment: ... For the people trying to help you, questions with just a link to "the code" and a huge number of lines of code can act as a deterrent.

Answer (score 5):

Your document class is based on `report`, so I assume your highest level of sectioning is `\chapter`. If you use the option `refsection=chapter` and add a `\printbibliography` at the end of each chapter you get a bibliography for each chapter separately.

```
\documentclass[british]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber, refsection=chapter]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Lorem}
Lorem ipsum \autocite{sigfridsson} dolor \autocite{geer,worman}
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography, title=\bibname\ for \chaptername~\thechapter]

\chapter{Dolor}
Lorem ipsum \autocite{sigfridsson} dolor \autocite{knuth:ct:a,pines}
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography, title=\bibname\ for \chaptername~\thechapter]

\chapter{Sit}
Lorem ipsum \autocite{sigfridsson} dolor \autocite{geer,cicero,companion}
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography, title=\bibname\ for \chaptername~\thechapter]
\end{document}
```

The MWE uses `heading=subbibliography` so that the heading is typeset as a `\section` subordinate to the current `\chapter`.

[image: The first chapter cites <code>sigfridsson</code>, <code>worman</code> and <code>geer</code>. The bibliography shows these three entries.]

[image: The second chapter cites <code>sigfridsson</code>, <code>knuth:ct:a</code> and <code>pines</code>. The bibliography shows these three entries.]

---

**Edit** your MWE shows at least one problem: You have `refsegment=chapter`. But you should be using `refsection=chapter`.

`refsection`s keep their contents completely local and completely independent of other `refsection`s, which means that the numbers in the bibliography restart for each chapter. `refsegment`s basically only add an attribute to entries and are usually only used to filter bibliographies: If you use `refsegment`s, all entries still belong to one global list.

You can find a bit about the differences between `refsection` and `refsegment` in the `biblatex` documentation (§3.7.4 and §3.7.5), in [Reset the counter of references in each chapter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/65379/35864) and [Multiple bibliographies, multiple styles, discontiguous regions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/446368/35864).